# After performing Blob to a file link, download a file with a size but cannot open the file : Nextjs

Tags: next.js, blob, contentful

So after investing hours, trying to figure out why blob was not working with next/link. I got it working by using a  in theory you don't need a Link attribute for links to download files, but that's another different history. The problem is, now I am getting issues with the file that I get after the download. I noticed the file have a size, but when try to open it does not work. This component with this link supposed to receive 3 types of possible files from a url comming from an API call(so not public, just in case). The types are video(can be mp4,ogg, etc), image(png,jpg,webmp, gif, etc) and pdf. Both, as  I mentioned before, I get them from the API call, (url and type).

And yes, I have read another answers related to that problem, but...no luck

So my basic component looks like(removed unnecesary props, styling functionality to show here):

```
export default function Link({ children, href, typeFile}: LinkProps) {
  
  const [src, setSrc] = useState('');
  const hrefReplace = href.replace(/^https?:/, '');



  useEffect(() => {
    const blob = new Blob([hrefReplace], { type: typeFile });
    const fileRef = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    setSrc(fileRef);
  }, [hrefReplace, typeFile]);


  return (
    <span>
      <a href={src} download>
       {children}
      </a>
    </span>
  );
}
```

I did my own research and somehow it can be related to 2 things, one is that the type that blob is receiving might be not correct, and the second possibility, the file is not ready when the download starts. So what I tested first was...to change the type so for example instead of 'video/mp4' I changed to 'application/mp4' or 'application/video' but not result. Same with image and the other formats. For the second option I don't know because the example that I found was something made on HTML and javascript where the link in built with the page. So any type of idea or help is very welcome.

Let me know if you need more information to provide and thank you very much in advance.